# Sencha touch & Extjs6, Keyboard overlays input fields when using 3rd-party InputMethod in ios

Tags: ios, extjs, keyboard, overlay, extjs6

There is a formpanel which has a lot of input fields with Extjs6 Modern.

[image]

I am using ios 9.3.1 and 3rd-party input method. When I tap one input (e.g. the Rio textarea), the keyboard shows, but it overlays the input.

[image]

It goes well when I use the default inputMethod of ios. The view moves up and docks to the top of the keyboard.

[image]

Sencha touch has the same issue.

Do you have any workaround?

Comment: No, I haven't, but have you reported this bug at the Sencha forum?

Comment: @Alexander Yes, I have.
See https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?310873-Keyboard-overlay-the-input-field-when-using-3rd-party-inputmethod-in-ios&p=1135107

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an solution
use plugin [cordova-plugin-keyboard](https://github.com/cjpearson/cordova-plugin-keyboard)，and add those preferences to config.xml

```
<preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="true" />  
<preference name="DisableScrollingWhenKeyboardShrinksView" value="true" />
```

see http://blog.csdn.net/lovelyelfpop/article/details/52033045 for detail